# Mustache Templating: nested templates

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache

How can I use a nested template within mustache? Is there a way to do the same?

```
var tmpl="{{#data}} 
{{values}}
Name: {{name}}
//{{another_templ({{name.value}})}}
{{/values}}
{{/data}}"
```

Hope you guys got the question. I have not added the escape character for js validity since code is split across different lines.

Comment: Why don't you use partials? https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Partials

Answer (score 8):

You could use a lambda to nest the template:

```
function nested_template(template_string, translate) {
  return function() {
    return function(text, render) {
      return Mustache.to_html(template_string, translate(render(text)));
    };
  };
}

var template_string = 
  "{{#data}}"+
    "{{values}}"+
      "Name: {{name}}"+
      "{{#another_templ}}{{name}}{{/another_templ}}"+
    "{{/values}}"+
  "{{/data}}";

var another_template_string = "<b>{{name}}</b>"; // for example

var view = {
  data: {
    values: {
      name: "Test"
    }
  },
  another_templ: nested_template(another_template_string, function(text) {
    return {name: text};
  });
};

var result = Mustache.to_html(template_string, view);
```

Comment: I thought of this work aorund.. but i thought there might be something built into moustache.. I may be wrong..

Comment: @Harry: No, the only way are lambdas, because partials can't get parameters (except you hack them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656093/mustache-partials-using-variable-syntax-without-the).

Comment: I  would appreciate if you could direct me to some site that gives a good knowlegde abt mustache..

Comment: Sorry to bother but here you are basically reimplementing an existing feature in Mustache. You should use **partials** for this; I've been doing it since the first day and it will render your variables as with any other "normal", standard template. Are you sure you are using partials right, @marc?

Comment: Thanks for your question. IMO partials do not answer OP's questions, since they do not allow for passing an argument, but rely on the current data environment. Note that the technique in this answer allows reuse of the other template in /different/ contexts, whereas partials can only be used in a fixed context (since they expect a specific data environment, rather than getting an arbitrary argument).

Comment: First of all, note that we seem to be talking about different versons of Mustache here. "How can I use a nested template within mustache?". That's the OP's question. I think "Using partials" answers that. Still don't understand your reasoning. In your example, your "arbitrary argument" comes from the "specific data environment" you are passing to the lambda. I'd like to see what's in your example that cannot be done with a simple  `{{>partial}}`.

Comment: Since it's a very old question, it might very well be true that things have changed :) It is tough to say what OP wants if he doesn't accept any answer. But my impression is that he asks how to pass an argument to a tempate, `{{another_tpl({{name}})}}`. All the answers here explain how to do something like that. Think of a generic template that is used e.g. to make a text have a little icon besides it to invoke search functionality. Something like that should be usable with any text, including text generated via moustache itself. How would this be solved with partials?

Answer (score 8):

I have made an example of nested templates over at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU7Gx/). 
Here it is in detail:

First, set up your HTML

```
<div class="main"><!-- content here --></div>

<script type="text/html" id="tpl">
    {{#data}}
        {{#names}}
            Name: {{name}}
            {{#nested}}{{name}}{{/nested}}<br>
        {{/names}}
    {{/data}}
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="tpl-nested">
    &mdash; <b>{{name}}</b>
</script>​
```

Then the javascript (using jQuery)

```
function renderNested(template_string, translate) {
    return function() {
        return function(text, render) {
            return Mustache.to_html(template_string, translate(render(text)));
        };
    };
}

var template = $("#tpl").html();

var nested_template = $("#tpl-nested").html();

var model = {
    data: {
        names: [
            { name: "Foo" },
            { name: "Bar" }
        ],
        nested: renderNested(nested_template, function(text) {
            return { name: text };
        })
    }
};

var result = Mustache.to_html(template, model);

$(".main").html( result );
```

Comment: I went a similar direction except I put the name of the sub-template in the template, like {{#nested}}tpl-nested{{/nested}}, see https://jsfiddle.net/omnius/env3d7wk/ but the issue I ran into was that it didn't work when nesting multiple levels and I don't know why that doesn't work.  I thought I had understood that since I was using the same renderer all the way down, it should use the same data model, which includes the sub-template loader.  Any idea why my Fiddle doesn't do the sub-sub-templates?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method where we do string replacement before we compile the templates.
Subtemplates are called in the templates by:
{{#template}}**insertTheNameOfYourSubTemplateHere**{{/template}}

```
templates = {}

function compileTemplates(templateNamesArray) {
    for (index in templateNamesArray) {
        var templateName = templateNamesArray[index];
        var baseHTML = $('#' + templateName).html();

        var start = baseHTML.indexOf("{{#template}}");
        while(start != -1) {
            var end = baseHTML.indexOf('{{/template}}', start);
            var nestedTemplateName = baseHTML.slice(start + "{{#template}}".length, end);
            var nestedTemplateEl = $('#' + nestedTemplateName);
            if (nestedTemplateEl.length == 0) {
                throw "Could not find nested template '" + nestedTemplateName + "' for the template '" + templateName + "'";
            }
            baseHTML = baseHTML.slice(0, start) + nestedTemplateEl.html() + baseHTML.slice(end + '{{/template}}'.length);
            start = baseHTML.indexOf("{{#template}}", start);
        }
        templates[templateName] = Handlebars.compile(baseHTML);
    }
}

compileTemplates(["templateActiveThreadTab", "templateActiveThreadContent", "templateTodoItem"]);
```