# Is $.tmpl() stable and supported?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am planning on using `$.tmpl()` for a rather large enterprise application. It appears that it is now owned by the JQuery UI team and new development and support is being put on hold. Is this true?

Is it okay to start using the jquery template mechanism extensively?

Comment: Underscore.js and Mustache are two other, widely used JS templating solutions.

Comment: @mblase75 If I want to swap `$.tmpl()` with Underscore.js at a later time, is it easy to do without a lot of code changes?

Comment: Can't say I'm experienced with all three, but they all have slightly different syntaxes. But I'd suppose that whether it's easy to change one for the other depends on whether you want to go past basic templating.

Comment: @mblase75 Yes, it's basic templating, although I need to nest templates (not sure if this is supported by `$.tmpl()` although that's a different question)

Comment: Mustache claims to be "logic-less", so I'd start there and see if it's sufficient for your needs. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6846672/901048 for nested solutions with Mustache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html

That said, I've used it pretty extensively as it exists with no problems.

Comment: What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: I guess the JsRender stuff from the link above when it comes out, or the two that mblase75 mentioned above.

Comment: Should I download jquery.ui.js to use the template plugin?

Comment: No, $.tmpl is in its own js file and has no requirement for jquery ui. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Answer (score 0):

As BNL mentioned in his answer; [$.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) is no longer supported.

That being said, I've used it in several large web and mobile applications and I found it works like a charm in its current beta form.

Good luck with whatever you decide!